# Como forçar o Excel a respeitar a formatação durante a expansão de uma tabela dinâmica?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Boa noite, pessoal.

Cheguei ao meu limite da razão com o excel.

Criei um template para uma tabela de controle de valores de cheques. Porém, ao inserir mais linhas dinamicamente, através do uso do userform, o excel simplesmente não respeita a formatação da primeira linha da tabela aleatoriamente.

Além de não formatar A3 como "Moeda" e perder o alinhamento, H3 e J3 estão tendo uma alteração da cor da fonte.

Para completar, gostaria de saber se é possível preservar a Formatação Condicional existente em F2:M2, sendo que a tabela é dinâmica. Pretendo, futuramente, fazer com que um formulario atraves de macro apareça sempre que for adicionada uma "new sheet", para que a tabela seja gerada do zero (ou seja, nem mesmo a linha A2 existirá). É possível fazer formatação condicional por VBA?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.